# Python - Replace list of strings in a file text

Tags: python, loops, text, overwrite

I want to replace a part of text in a file text with python. My part of text to add is stored with a list as you can see with "a list".
I detect the part of the text with a counter that works well, my problem seems to be due to my part of ".write" which is defined in a loop with : "fichier_write.write("%.4\n" %a[:][i]) "

```
#The list I have to add in my file text
a = ['"A01.tiff", "B01.tiff"',
'"A02.tiff","B02.tiff"',
'"A03.tiff","B03.tiff"',
'"A04.tiff","B04.tiff"']

#The format expected is : (i have to suppress " ' " and " [ ] "
"A01.tiff", "B01.tiff",
"A02.tiff","B02.tiff",
"A03.tiff","B03.tiff",
"A04.tiff","B04.tiff"


fichier = open('original.txt',"r")
nb_ligne = 0
chaine = 'image_list ='
for ligne in fichier:
    nb_ligne += 1
    if chaine in ligne:
        break
fichier.close()

#I try to modify my file text with :

fichier_read = open('original.txt',"r")  
fichier_write = open('modified.txt',"w")  

compteur=0.
for ligne in fichier_read:
  compteur=compteur+1
  if compteur != nb_ligne :
    fichier_write.write(ligne)
  else :
    fichier_write.write('image_list = \n')
    for i in range(len(a)):
        fichier_write.write("%.4\n" %a[:][i])  
    break


fichier_write.close()  
fichier_read.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

%a[:][i] is an array. You are likely looking for %a[i]. The format also has a slight error in that it should be
`fichier_write.write("%.4s\n" %a[i])`
Notice the s at the end for string.

Comment: Thanks for help but i have still an error : "unsupported format character ' " ...

Comment: Is this python 2 or 3? Also worth trying %(a[i])

Comment: it must be the 2.7.6 i think

Comment: Didn't realize these were strings, you'll need         fichier_write.write("%.4s\n" %a[i]) to get the first 4 characters. Note this includes the quotation mark